# DynamoDB Authentication With AWS SDK for Java

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm using AWS SDK for Java, and I need to authenticate in the database by a ARN User/Role.
How can I do this? Actually I'm authenticating using accessKey and secretKey, but I need to change (rules of organization) to use ARN.

Actually authenticating by this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableDynamoDBRepositories(basePackages = "mypackage.repository")
public class DynamoDBConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public AmazonDynamoDB amazonDynamoDB(AWSCredentials AWSCredentials,
                                         @Value("${aws.dynamoDBUrl}") String dynamoDBUrl){

        AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder builder = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard()
                .withEndpointConfiguration(new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration(dynamoDBUrl, "sa-east-1"))
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(AWSCredentials));
        AmazonDynamoDB build = builder.build();
        return build;
    }

    @Bean
    public AWSCredentials awsCredentials(@Value("${aws.accessKey}") String accessKey,
                                         @Value("${aws.secretKey}") String secretKey){
        return new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);
    }

}
```

Comment: ARNs represent Amazon resources. They're simply identifiers, not values such as credentials. Can you elaborate on the requirement for an ARN here? Or do you mean an IAM Role?

Answer (score 0):

API to connect does not support a user arn, both keys are required.

Typically, when I develop I setup the credentials and config to do my authentication that I need.   That way I don't have to pass them around in code.   Then when your code runs on an AWS Compute resource you can specify a Role for your compute instance (examples include:  EC2, Fargate Container, and Lambda).  Then this role can be granted the permissions you need.

This concept is typically more secure as you are not managing any credentials in your application.

The only time I have dealt with local credentials is when I developing something installed on the desktop computer.  In those cases, I have used the SSO API to acquire both keys, and the session token.